# How to crop a portion of the screen in the Clipboard?

Tags: print-screen

I need often to create Slides from portions of screen. I've found several tools like Shutter which are able to capture an image, however my need is to put the image **directly** in the Clipboard so that I can paste in in my LibreOffice quickly.
Any idea ?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `PrtScr`, paste that in and crop it there?

Comment: cropping needs some variables to be set. How to decide what will stay?

Comment: But Printscreen stores the image in the Pictures folder. I need to manually open and crop

Comment: Hi Jacob. I'm looking for a tool which lets you select the cropping area on the screen (like shutter) which however stores in the image directly on the Clipboard. With dozens of images to be grabbed that would help me a lot

Comment: The default shift+prnscr shortcut allows selecting an area to grab and then popup appears which has option to copy to clipboard. That's twostep process but works. Let me know if that's an acceptable answer for you

Comment: @serg, that's awesome! I wish I knew this before.

Comment: By the way, the normal PrtSc pop up as well as shift+PrtSc both have a "Copy to Clipboard" option (on 14.04 at least).

Comment: @Serg depends the windows/desktop manager. ie. xfce doesn't. It would be helpful if OP says which DE he's using.

Comment: @Braiam Typically users specify if they use different DE ; if not - assume Unity. That's my default protocol and I've never had issue with it so far

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd>.

Then you will be able to select a portion of a screen.

After that you will be able to choose either to copy it to clipboard or save as a file.

Answer (score 7):

#### Use gnome-screenshot (already on your system if you use Unity or Gnome)

The easiest is to use good old `gnome-screenshot`, by default installed. Simply put the command:

```
gnome-screenshot -ac
```

under a shortcut key. The cursor will change into a cross, and your selection is copied to the clipboard directly.

#### Add it to a shortcut

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
gnome-screenshot -ac
```

#### Explanation

From `man screenshot`:

```
   -a, --area
          Grab  an  area  of  the  screen instead of the entire
          screen.
```

and:

```
   -c, --clipboard
          Send the grab directly to the clipboard.
```

Comment: Didn't know it had -c flag , that'll be useful. +1

Comment: @Serg Thanks :) I remembered from earlier occasions :)

Answer (score 1):

Install [`shutter`](http://shutter-project.org/). Once installed, run it; you can snap a selection of screen  directly (1) (and copy and paste immediatly with CTRL-C CTRL-V), or edit it (2) and add markers, labels, highlights and crops:

[image: shutter's own screenshot]

It has extensive configuration and can reside in your panel (3).

It's in the Universe repository, so it's just a

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

away.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> is working for me.

Without any additional installations.